# How to display changing data in XUL

Tags: rss, dynamic-data, xul

I'm trying to build a firefox extension which can get rss feeds and display them in a popup panel. But I'm not aware about how to display feeds in a panel(I know how to display static text).Because the feed is varying all the time.
Any help regarding this matter will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) to call a function that redraws the panel at the time interval you specify?

Answer (score 1):

You can create DOM elements inside a XUL popup panel using JavaScript, but you have to remember that the panel requires the XHTML namespace:

`<panel id="your-id" noautohide="true" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

and instead of using:

`document.createElement("p"); //for example`

you would need to use:

`document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","html:p");`

You can get the popup reference by id and just create and append elements as you need them. Then the following might help:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/PopupGuide/OpenClose: